# Replying with multiple answers in Akka

Tags: scala, akka

I have a communication to one Actor:

```
val future = ask(foo, Bar())(1 seconds).mapTo[Row]
val result = Await.result(future, 1 seconds)
```

This works fine as long as I only send one `Row` back from `foo`. How would I reply with multiple `Row`s:

```
sender() ! Row()
sender() ! Row()
```

subsequently in `foo`?

Comment: Have you considered using streams, or Futures directly? Most of the time, using actors isn't the right way to go with things. We had someone ask a question about actors in our company-internal Scala channel and 4 separate people queried him not to use actors.

Comment: Not yet. In this case having the guarantees that Actors provide is an exact fit, so would really like to use them.

Comment: Are you sure? Your question looks more like you want to answer with a stream of results.

Comment: Do you need to use the ask pattern? if the sender was also an actor you can just send messages back and forth

Comment: I would like to use the `ask` since I need to know when all results were received. Using a terminate message would be an option but is of course not as nice as when it would just work without one.

Comment: Then you can't. You can either flatMap all the futures you need in the actor and send all the results at once, e.g within a tuple, or keep sending messages to the referenced actor (which you can't with the ask pattern)

Comment: It is not completely clear to me how you are expecting to get your results. Are you expecting a `Future[List[Row]]`? Or are you thinking you'd await on your `Future[Row]` multiple times, and get a different row each time (it doesn't work that way)?

The `Await.result` in your code seems to imply that you don't really need the results asynchronously?

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned in the comments, the ask pattern will only work if you send all the rows as a single message. Using `akka-stream` is a great solution for building a processor for this:

```
val barActor = system.actorOf(Props(new BarActor()))

def runQuery(): Future[Seq[Row]] = {
  // complete when EndOfQuery message is received 
  val runnableGraph = Source.actorRef[DataProtocol](Int.MaxValue, OverflowStrategy.fail)
    .takeWhile(elem => {
      elem match {
        case _:Row => true
        case _ | EndOfQuery => false
      }
    })
    .toMat(Sink.seq[DataProtocol])(Keep.both)

  // keep both the ActorRef and the Future[DataProtocol]
  val (actor, future) = runnableGraph.run()

  // issue query to actor
  barActor ! Query(actor)

  // only Row messages were emitted:
  future.map(_.asInstanceOf[Seq[Row]])
}

val data = Await.result(runQuery(), Duration.Inf)
```

As you mentioned in your question, you'll need a stop message.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I wanted to use Akka since it is really straight-forward and elegant. Sadly to me this does not seem as elegant :(

Comment: @abergmeier Another solution could be to reply with an `Iterator[Row]` which might work. Akka has some really useful patterns, but took some getting used to.

Answer (score 0):

You can respond only with one object. What about reponding a list?

```
class Foo extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case Bar(): sender() ! List.of(Row(), Row())
  }
}

val future = ask(foo, Bar())(1 seconds).mapTo[List[Row]]
val result = Await.result(future, 1 seconds)

val row0 = result(0);
val row1 = result(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you are hoping to accomplish, without more context. I suspect that @lasekio's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51251385/31506) is likely exactly what you are looking for.

But if you are looking for an asynchronous streaming solution, that is, if you want to process rows as they come in, rather than wait until they are all available (perhaps because there are more rows than will fit in memory - millions/billions), then, well, then you should use Akka Streams. But since it seems like you are against that, here's an alternative that is pure Akka + Futures:

The actor will be returning the row, plus a future of the next row. Since you need a way to indicate that there are no more rows, I'm wrapping the result in an `Option` in my example, where `Some` contains the `Row` and future of next `Row`, while `None` means there are no more rows. You can also create a separate type, or use `null`, just something that clearly indicates that there is no further data. On the actor side, you'd do:

```
case _: Bar =>
  if (/*... there are more rows...*/) sender() ! Some((Row(), (context.self ? Bar()))
  else sender() ! None
```

On the consumer side:

```
def consumeRows(rowsFut: Future[Option[(Row,Future[_])]]): Unit = {
  rowsFut.foreach {
    _.foreach {
      case (row: Row, nextRowsFut: Future[Option[(Row,Future[_])]]) =>
        // Do something with row
        println(row)
        consumeRows(nextRowsFut)
  }
}
val rowsFut = ask(foo, Bar())(1 seconds).mapTo[Option[(Row,Future[_])]]
consumeRows(rowsFut)
```